# Errors compiling wxWidgets

Tags: c++, graphics, wxwidgets

I am trying to run the sample code shown [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/). I built wxWidgets from source using MinGW, with this command: mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=0 BUILD=debug. In my Eclipse settings, I add -Iwx288/include, -Lwx288/lib, -lwxbase28d_gcc_custom and -lwxmsw28d_core_gcc_custom. I get very very confused, due to the number of ways to compile and inexperience with linkers. I get these errors, what am I doing wrong? I'm not even citing wxMutex in my program.

```
23:15:19 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project A ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Files\\Programming\\C++\\A\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "include\\wx\\thrimpl.o" "..\\include\\wx\\thrimpl.cpp" 
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:18:1: error: 'wxMutex' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:29:1: error: 'wxMutex' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:34:6: error: 'wxMutex' has not been declared
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:34:22: error: non-member function 'bool IsOk()' cannot have cv-qualifier
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:36:12: error: 'm_internal' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:36:26: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: At global scope:
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:39:1: error: 'wxMutexError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:47:1: error: 'wxMutexError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:55:1: error: 'wxMutexError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:224:1: error: 'wxCondition' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:235:1: error: 'wxCondition' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:240:6: error: 'wxCondition' has not been declared
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:240:26: error: non-member function 'bool IsOk()' cannot have cv-qualifier
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:240:6: error: redefinition of 'bool IsOk()'
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:34:6: error: 'bool IsOk()' previously defined here
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:242:12: error: 'm_internal' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:242:26: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: At global scope:
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:245:1: error: 'wxCondError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:253:1: error: 'wxCondError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:261:1: error: 'wxCondError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:269:1: error: 'wxCondError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:281:1: error: 'wxSemaphore' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:291:1: error: 'wxSemaphore' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:296:6: error: 'wxSemaphore' has not been declared
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:296:26: error: non-member function 'bool IsOk()' cannot have cv-qualifier
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:296:6: error: redefinition of 'bool IsOk()'
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:34:6: error: 'bool IsOk()' previously defined here
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:298:12: error: 'm_internal' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:298:26: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: At global scope:
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:301:1: error: 'wxSemaError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:309:1: error: 'wxSemaError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:317:1: error: 'wxSemaError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:325:1: error: 'wxSemaError' does not name a type
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:299:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:243:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp: In function 'bool IsOk()':
..\include\wx\thrimpl.cpp:37:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

23:15:20 Build Finished (took 657ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to compile `include/wx/thrimpl.cpp`? It's not your file, it's part of wxWidgets and it shouldn't be compiled as part of your project. Just remove it from the list of project files.

Comment: Removing it works, but why is it in wx288\include in the first place?

Comment: It is used by wxWidgets. In an ideal world it would have been located in the `private` subdirectory but this file predates that directory existence, so here you are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are either missing something in your include path or some of the Defines required by `wxWidgets` in order to process `wxWidgets Header-Files` correctly

WX comes with a tool called `wx-config` ( should be located somewhere in `wxWidgets/bin` if your build was successful)

`wx-config` is a shell-script, you can execute it using `mingw-msys`

`wx-config --cxxflags` produces all Include Paths and Defines needed to compile object files.
`wx-config --libs` takes care of everything needed to link the program

I would recommend using `wx-config` in your `makefile/builder/...`.
or check the output produced by it and compare it to your build process

Samples form my current installation:

`$ wx-config --cxxflags --static=no --debug=yes --unicode=no -I/wx/lib/wx/include/msw-ansi-debug-2.8 -I/wx/include/wx-2.8 -D_WXDEBUG_ -DWXUSINGDLL -D_WXMSW_ -mthreads`

$ ./wx-config --libs --static=no --debug=yes --unicode=no -L/wx/lib  -mthreads  -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -lwx_mswd_richtext-2.8 -lwx_mswd_aui-2.8 -lwx_mswd_xrc-2.8 -lwx_mswd_qa-2.8 -lwx_mswd_html-2.8 -lwx_mswd_adv-2.8 -lwx_mswd_core-2.8 -lwx_based_xml-2.8 -lwx_based_net-2.8 -lwx_based-2.8